# POSIX Characters not working on CodeBuild Server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, aws-codebuild

I am trying to use a linux command to get a version number from my package.json file in a node project during the build. I am using a Ubuntu 18.04 image in Codebuild. I have the following command that I would like to run from the buildspec.yml:

```
export PACKAGE_NAME=$(cat package.json | grep name | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g')
```

The problem with this command is that the awk -F: is invalid YAML. To remedy this, I added a POSIX space character:

```
export PACKAGE_NAME=$(cat package.json | grep name | head -1 | awk -F:[[:space:]] '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g')
```

This command works on Git Bash in Windows, it works on Ubuntu WSL, it works on Ubuntu 18.04 launched in an EC2 instance, but it fails to work when run by CodeBuild (variable comes back empty), which doesn't make any sense to me as a Linux command should work the same on the same type of Linux. I verified that the package.json is in the root and accessible.

So is there a syntactically better way for me to achieve my goal, or is there a way to make CodeBuild read the command the same way the rest of linuxes do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing jq on my image and then using it instead:

```
PACKAGE_VERSION=$(jq -r ".version" package.json)
```